# Hook or Modify Class at runtime

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to modify my java test suite such that I don't report on Skipped tests to fulfill a business requirement.

TestNG allows you to write Custom Reporters and Listeners but in this case I want to amend the Junit report  that is consumed by our Jenkins and SonarQube instances.

Digging in to the testNG code I see this:

```
private void initializeDefaultListeners() {
    m_testListeners.add(new ExitCodeListener(this));

    if (m_useDefaultListeners) {
        addReporter(SuiteHTMLReporter.class);
        addReporter(Main.class);
        addReporter(FailedReporter.class);
        addReporter(XMLReporter.class);
    if (System.getProperty("oldTestngEmailableReporter") != null) {
        addReporter(EmailableReporter.class);
    } else if (System.getProperty("noEmailableReporter") == null) {
        addReporter(EmailableReporter2.class);
    }
    addReporter(JUnitReportReporter.class);
    if (m_verbose != null && m_verbose > 4) {
        addListener(new VerboseReporter("[TestNG] "));
    }    
}
```

So it appears that testNG is is enabling the JUnitReportReporter by default, so extending that class isn't going to have the desired effect.

Is there a way in java to either hook in to that class and make the changes I need to the generateReport method, or modify that class at runtime?
I could patch testNG itself but that doesn't seem sustainable or good practice, or I could redo my Build Automation process, but that is owned by another team so I'd prefer something else.

Comment: You can use reflection, but again, not good practice. There's no "good practice" way to achieve this, you either have to hack the framework or deal with it elsewhere (like removing the tests instead of skipping them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which you can go about fixing this problem.

Please make sure you are using the latest released version of TestNG [ It is currently **6.13.1** ]

**Approach #1 : Classpath overriding**

In this approach you basically start off by duplicating `org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter` in your project and then you alter it locally to suite your needs. This will spoof Java into finding your variant first and ignore what resides in TestNG. You can then modify the class to suite your needs.

**Approach #2 : Disable default listeners**

TestNG lets you disable the default listeners by setting the property `usedefaultlisteners` to `false`. Below is how you would do it via Maven.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </property>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can now build your own variant of the reporter and then inject it.

**Approach #3 : Have your listeners run in an order**

By default TestNG does not let you define the order of your listeners. But there's a way of doing that.

1. Disable all default listeners.
2. Define a proxy listener into which you will wire in all the other listeners (both default and custom listeners written by you) via your own defined SPI mechanism (Service Loaders)
3. You wire in only your proxy listener which will eventually hook up all the other listeners.
4. Build a listener which you would configure to be executed at the end, which when executed would basically look for the JUnit report files, and then parse them as xml file wherein you would remove the extraneous information to suite your needs.

I created a blog post on this, which talks about how to have TestNG execute listeners in an order. You can refer to it for more information [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/12/26/dears-listeners-stand-in-q-please/).

You can pick up whichever approach works for you.

Comment: Thank you, #1 is clever.  Do you know what order the JVM will load classes in the classpath?  How do I guarantee that a class I compile in my Jar/War/Ear is preferred over some other class in the path?  
Ultimately I will probably just turn off the default listeners, overload JUnitReportReporter, and then manually enable all the default listeners (swapping my overloaded class for the JUnitReportReporter).

Comment: @Chris - I think forming the classpath would boil down to the build tool. I dont have any document that can back my theory. I am stating this based on experience. From my limited experience I have noticed that Java always first finds `.class` from your project (which is essentially the build path) before it starts searching the jars available in the classpath.